# Encoding. How to develop projects PHP + Ajax

Tags: encoding

Encoding. How to develop projects PHP + Ajax?  UTF8 or CP1251.

Comment: Denis, I think the down-votes may be from folks who didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use UTF-8. Always and everywhere.

Comment: agreed. no point using anything else.